# fatal error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I have no idea what this means. But here is the code that it supposely is happening in.

```
//=======================================================================================
// d3dApp.cpp by Frank Luna (C) 2008 All Rights Reserved.
//=======================================================================================

#include "d3dApp.h"
#include <stream>

LRESULT CALLBACK
MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static D3DApp* app = 0;

    switch( msg )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            // Get the 'this' pointer we passed to CreateWindow via the lpParam parameter.
            CREATESTRUCT* cs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            app = (D3DApp*)cs->lpCreateParams;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Don't start processing messages until after WM_CREATE.
    if( app )
        return app->msgProc(msg, wParam, lParam);
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

D3DApp::D3DApp(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    mhAppInst   = hInstance;
    mhMainWnd   = 0;
    mAppPaused  = false;
    mMinimized  = false;
    mMaximized  = false;
    mResizing   = false;

    mFrameStats = L"";

    md3dDevice          = 0;
    mSwapChain          = 0;
    mDepthStencilBuffer = 0;
    mRenderTargetView   = 0;
    mDepthStencilView   = 0;
    mFont               = 0;

    mMainWndCaption = L"D3D10 Application";
    md3dDriverType  = D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    mClearColor     = D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    mClientWidth    = 800;
    mClientHeight   = 600;
}

D3DApp::~D3DApp()
{
    ReleaseCOM(mRenderTargetView);
    ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilView);
    ReleaseCOM(mSwapChain);
    ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilBuffer);
    ReleaseCOM(md3dDevice);
    ReleaseCOM(mFont);
}

HINSTANCE D3DApp::getAppInst()
{
    return mhAppInst;
}

HWND D3DApp::getMainWnd()
{
    return mhMainWnd;
}

int D3DApp::run()
{
    MSG msg = {0};

    mTimer.reset();

    while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        // If there are Window messages then process them.
        if(PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ))
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        // Otherwise, do animation/game stuff.
        else
        {   
            mTimer.tick();

            if( !mAppPaused )
                updateScene(mTimer.getDeltaTime()); 
            else
                Sleep(50);

            drawScene();
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

void D3DApp::initApp()
{
    initMainWindow();
    initDirect3D();

    D3DX10_FONT_DESC fontDesc;
    fontDesc.Height          = 24;
    fontDesc.Width           = 0;
    fontDesc.Weight          = 0;
    fontDesc.MipLevels       = 1;
    fontDesc.Italic          = false;
    fontDesc.CharSet         = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    fontDesc.OutputPrecision = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
    fontDesc.Quality         = DEFAULT_QUALITY;
    fontDesc.PitchAndFamily  = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;
    wcscpy(fontDesc.FaceName, L"Times New Roman");

    D3DX10CreateFontIndirect(md3dDevice, &fontDesc, &mFont);
}

void D3DApp::onResize()
{
    // Release the old views, as they hold references to the buffers we
    // will be destroying.  Also release the old depth/stencil buffer.

    ReleaseCOM(mRenderTargetView);
    ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilView);
    ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilBuffer);


    // Resize the swap chain and recreate the render target view.

    HR(mSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(1, mClientWidth, mClientHeight, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0));
    ID3D10Texture2D* backBuffer;
    HR(mSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&backBuffer)));
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, 0, &mRenderTargetView));
    ReleaseCOM(backBuffer);


    // Create the depth/stencil buffer and view.

    D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;

    depthStencilDesc.Width     = mClientWidth;
    depthStencilDesc.Height    = mClientHeight;
    depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.Format    = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count   = 1; // multisampling must match
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0; // swap chain values.
    depthStencilDesc.Usage          = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthStencilDesc.BindFlags      = D3D10_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0; 
    depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags      = 0;

    HR(md3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, 0, &mDepthStencilBuffer));
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilBuffer, 0, &mDepthStencilView));


    // Bind the render target view and depth/stencil view to the pipeline.

    md3dDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &mRenderTargetView, mDepthStencilView);


    // Set the viewport transform.

    D3D10_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    vp.Width    = mClientWidth;
    vp.Height   = mClientHeight;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    md3dDevice->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
}

void D3DApp::updateScene(float dt)
{
    // Code computes the average frames per second, and also the 
    // average time it takes to render one frame.

    static int frameCnt = 0;
    static float t_base = 0.0f;

    frameCnt++;

    // Compute averages over one second period.
    if( (mTimer.getGameTime() - t_base) >= 1.0f )
    {
        float fps = (float)frameCnt; // fps = frameCnt / 1
        float mspf = 1000.0f / fps;

        std::wostringstream outs;   
        outs.precision(6);
        outs << L"FPS: " << fps << L"\n" 
             << "Milliseconds: Per Frame: " << mspf;
        mFrameStats = outs.str();

        // Reset for next average.
        frameCnt = 0;
        t_base  += 1.0f;
    }
}

void D3DApp::drawScene()
{
    md3dDevice->ClearRenderTargetView(mRenderTargetView, mClearColor);
    md3dDevice->ClearDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilView, D3D10_CLEAR_DEPTH|D3D10_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);
}

LRESULT D3DApp::msgProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch( msg )
    {
    // WM_ACTIVATE is sent when the window is activated or deactivated.  
    // We pause the game when the window is deactivated and unpause it 
    // when it becomes active.  
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        if( LOWORD(wParam) == WA_INACTIVE )
        {
            mAppPaused = true;
            mTimer.stop();
        }
        else
        {
            mAppPaused = false;
            mTimer.start();
        }
        return 0;

    // WM_SIZE is sent when the user resizes the window.  
    case WM_SIZE:
        // Save the new client area dimensions.
        mClientWidth  = LOWORD(lParam);
        mClientHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
        if( md3dDevice )
        {
            if( wParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED )
            {
                mAppPaused = true;
                mMinimized = true;
                mMaximized = false;
            }
            else if( wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED )
            {
                mAppPaused = false;
                mMinimized = false;
                mMaximized = true;
                onResize();
            }
            else if( wParam == SIZE_RESTORED )
            {

                // Restoring from minimized state?
                if( mMinimized )
                {
                    mAppPaused = false;
                    mMinimized = false;
                    onResize();
                }

                // Restoring from maximized state?
                else if( mMaximized )
                {
                    mAppPaused = false;
                    mMaximized = false;
                    onResize();
                }
                else if( mResizing )
                {
                    // If user is dragging the resize bars, we do not resize 
                    // the buffers here because as the user continuously 
                    // drags the resize bars, a stream of WM_SIZE messages are
                    // sent to the window, and it would be pointless (and slow)
                    // to resize for each WM_SIZE message received from dragging
                    // the resize bars.  So instead, we reset after the user is 
                    // done resizing the window and releases the resize bars, which 
                    // sends a WM_EXITSIZEMOVE message.
                }
                else // API call such as SetWindowPos or mSwapChain->SetFullscreenState.
                {
                    onResize();
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;

    // WM_EXITSIZEMOVE is sent when the user grabs the resize bars.
    case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
        mAppPaused = true;
        mResizing  = true;
        mTimer.stop();
        return 0;

    // WM_EXITSIZEMOVE is sent when the user releases the resize bars.
    // Here we reset everything based on the new window dimensions.
    case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
        mAppPaused = false;
        mResizing  = false;
        mTimer.start();
        onResize();
        return 0;

    // WM_DESTROY is sent when the window is being destroyed.
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    // The WM_MENUCHAR message is sent when a menu is active and the user presses 
    // a key that does not correspond to any mnemonic or accelerator key. 
    case WM_MENUCHAR:
        // Don't beep when we alt-enter.
        return MAKELRESULT(0, MNC_CLOSE);

    // Catch this message so to prevent the window from becoming too small.
    case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.x = 200;
        ((MINMAXINFO*)lParam)->ptMinTrackSize.y = 200; 
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(mhMainWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}


void D3DApp::initMainWindow()
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = MainWndProc; 
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = mhAppInst;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"D3DWndClassName";

    if( !RegisterClass(&wc) )
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"RegisterClass FAILED", 0, 0);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    // Compute window rectangle dimensions based on requested client area dimensions.
    RECT R = { 0, 0, mClientWidth, mClientHeight };
    AdjustWindowRect(&R, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);
    int width  = R.right - R.left;
    int height = R.bottom - R.top;

    mhMainWnd = CreateWindow(L"D3DWndClassName", mMainWndCaption.c_str(), 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, 0, 0, mhAppInst, this); 
    if( !mhMainWnd )
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"CreateWindow FAILED", 0, 0);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    ShowWindow(mhMainWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(mhMainWnd);
}

void D3DApp::initDirect3D()
{
    // Fill out a DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC to describe our swap chain.

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width  = mClientWidth;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = mClientHeight;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    sd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    // No multisampling.
    sd.SampleDesc.Count   = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    sd.BufferUsage  = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.BufferCount  = 1;
    sd.OutputWindow = mhMainWnd;
    sd.Windowed     = true;
    sd.SwapEffect   = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    sd.Flags        = 0;


    // Create the device.

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)  
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    HR( D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
            0,                 //default adapter
            md3dDriverType,
            0,                 // no software device
            createDeviceFlags, 
            D3D10_SDK_VERSION,
            &sd,
            &mSwapChain,
            &md3dDevice) );


    // The remaining steps that need to be carried out for d3d creation
    // also need to be executed every time the window is resized.  So
    // just call the onResize method here to avoid code duplication.

    onResize();
}
```

Comment: What files does d3dApp.h include? Make sure it doesn't include itself.

Comment: I guess visual studio isn't kind enough to print a bit of "in file included from ..." to point you toward the include path that caused the recursion? I know gcc will.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some where an include file that has no include guard is including itself (directly or indirectly).

Use /showIncludes ("Configuration Properties/C/C++/Advanced/Show Includes" in the IDE's project options) to get help with this.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to fix your problem is at the top of all of your **header** files add:

```
#pragma once
```

Do this always everytime you make a header file in C++.  If your compiler doesn't support the above (I seriously doubt anyone uses a compiler that doesn't support it, Visual Studio which you use does) then you can use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

The `#pragma once` directive ensures that your includes will only be included once.

You will get the error you got if you have the following situation:

**file: a.h**

```
#include "b.h"
```

**file: b.h**

```
#include "a.h"
```

Then in your main app you include one of the 2 header files.

You can fix your situation by doing the following:

**file: a.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "b.h"
```

**file: b.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "a.h"
```

Comment: I always thought `#pragma` directives are always implementation defined (except for when initiated with an `STDC` token). If they are, it is almost always safer to use include guards, even if they are more tedious and ugly.

Comment: @dreamlax: All popular compilers implement `#pragma once`.  They are less error prone, and less code so they are preferred even know they are not standard.

Comment: Is there a a difference between #pragma once and #ifndef / #define?

Comment: @Jon: No but `#ifndef/#define` is more error prone because you need to explicitly specify a define name, maybe you will copy / paste into a different file.  Also less code to just to `#pragma once`.

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: There are compilers not supporting `#pragma once`, e.g. Wind River DIAB, Altium CTC. Are they popular? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

`std::stringstream` is in the `sstream` header, so:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your solution was recursive inclusion as Michael Burr stated, but for the record it can also happen with only correct inclusions, when the hierarchy is too deep.

For instance, if you have 1024 files, each one including only the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue when I accidentally had:

```
header/foo.hpp
source/foo.hpp
```

Rather than:

```
header/foo.hpp
source/foo.cpp
```

Thus causing:

```cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
```

To cause this error. Thought I'd add this answer as I was feeling stumped: no deep include chain, no forgotten header guard, I wasn't doing `#include "foo.cpp"`... except I was and didn't realise it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused because I copied the contents of a cpp into the header that was being referenced in the cpp.